# Need the Lodash combination properities to get the screenName from array

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
[{
    _id: 55 d5f0c8aead93d1d97f83c3,
    socialAuth: {
        linkedin: [],
        instagram: [],
        youtube: [],
        twitter: [{
            screenName: "Ammruth"
        }],
        facebook: []
    }
}, {
    _id: 55 d5f0c8aead93d1d97f83c3,
    socialAuth: {
        linkedin: [],
        instagram: [],
        youtube: [],
        twitter: [{
            screenName: "shamsher"
        }],
        facebook: []
    }
}]
```

I need screenNames from the twitter inner array objects to be printed from the above array objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also works if a user has multiple screen names:

```
var users = [your array];
var screenNames = _(users).pluck('socialAuth.twitter').flatten().pluck('screenName').value().join(', ');
```

Returns the list of screen names as a string comma and space separated.
This is done using lodash v3.10.1

Answer (score 1):

A vanilla JS way to do this is below. You don't really need Lodash.

```
var names = [];
arr.forEach(function(user){
  names.push(user.socialAuth.twitter[0].screenName);
});
```

with `arr` being the data structure you listed above.

Comment: thanks bro for the answer , is it possible instead of pushing the names into an array , can we have it in a single string.Like "Amruth, Shamsher"

Comment: you could do names.join(', ') - but that's assuming you only have first/last name combinations and not a long list of names

Answer (score 1):

This works with multiple screenNames per user:

```
var twitters = _.pluck(data, 'socialAuth.twitter');
var accounts = _.flatten(twitters);
var names = _.pluck(accounts, 'screenName');
```

This method is pretty slow; a more efficient one would be:

```
var names = [];
_.each(data, function (a) {
    var theseNames = _.pluck(a.socialAuth.twitter, 'screenName');
    names = names.concat(theseNames);
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/0eqjcgcc/

Comment: thanks for the answer bro but I get undefined in the array.

Comment: This code is untested. Give me a minute to try it out.

Comment: is it possible instead of pushing the names into an array , can we have it in a single string.Like "Amruth, Shamsher" @keizom

Comment: Yes, after the loop you can do `names.join(', ');`

Comment: Updated the answer with fixes.